# Phonetic/ phonological description of 2nd gen Chinese accent

Tags: accent

Quick question, and perhaps a natural extension of some of my previous questions.

For the girl speaking [here at 1:09](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x9h81jfiwic&t=1m9s), what phonetic and phonological characteristics of her accent, and how do they give it away that she is Chinese American?

While she definitely has LA area intonation patterns, I don't think solely that comprises her accent, as I can certainly imagine caucasian speakers from LA speaking with that intonation.

I feel, vaguely, there's something about her pitch being different on average, and perhaps something about her formants being broader(?), almost post-pubescent, if that makes any sense at all? If not, please just disregard this.

Comment: Interesting question. I've suspected that there exist certain characteristics not just in second-generation Asian-Americans but also Australians of Asian descent. However I've never been able to characterise these speech variations in phonetic terms. Even I'm not 100% sure the effect exists. I'd advise a little blind trial to determine whether you can really distinguish second-generation speakers on phonetic grounds alone. I would be interested in seeing whether there's any scholarly work on this.

Comment: [The related question here](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/14986/what-gives-rise-to-racial-accents-timbre?rq=1) is of particular interest, especially in its skepticism about whether speakers can really reliably distinguish such accents.